# How to have more fun with my female students?

Tags: supervision, germany

It's a couple of years that I have moved to Europe and working here as a research group leader. In my home country in Latin America, we are much more relaxed in our interactions with each other and enjoy life to the fullest; that is, for example, flirting with female students and have fun is something common.

I have realized that people in Europe are much more strict and prude. How can I overcome this cultural difference and enjoy my time in Germany?

Comment: I removed a few comments and [moved the others to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135084/discussion-on-question-by-ralf-how-to-have-more-fun-with-my-female-students). Please keep a civil tone in the discussion according to the [Code of Conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct). Please read the post notice and [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230) before posting another comment, and beware that we can only move comments to chat once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're right, there are different cultural norms at play here. Possibly right down to what is considered "flirting". Maybe I'm not the perfect person to answer this question, because I've only working in Germany briefly, but I want to jump in and answer it now, because I worry that it will get some quite aggressive reactions.

#### What is flirting?

For this question, it's really important to have a common understanding of what flirting is. In many parts of Europe, "flirting" is social iteration that indicates romantic and/or sexual interest in the person you are flirting with.

Now, it's infamously difficult to determine what is and isn't flirting. For example, I would say;

- Smiling a lot, normal amount of eye-contact; not flirting
- Smiling and more eye-contact than normal; maybe flirting
- Asking a group of people "Would you all like to get coffee?"; not flirting
- Asking one person "Would you like to get coffee?"; maybe flirting
- Asking one person "Do you want to go salsa dancing with me?"; flirting
- Saying "Nice nail polish"; not flirting
- Saying "Nice legs"; flirting (and quite creepy, in most situations)

But I'm sure there will be people who would disagree with all those assessments. So it's fuzzy, there is a spectrum from "just friendly" to "very flirty" and it's likely location specific. I'm not trying to say that mine is the only correct labelling of these examples, just that we need to agree on one, in order to discuss this topic.

If you wouldn't interact that way with someone you aren't attracted to (for example, a straight man with another man), it's very likely flirting.

#### May I flirt with my students in Germany?

**No**, bad idea. Never do things that may "indicate romantic and/or sexual interest" with someone who is your junior, or with whom there is significant power imbalance. The principle here is that they may feel pressured to reciprocate your advances, or unable to set boundaries, for fear of retaliation.

One potential exception; if your junior flirts with you first, some would say it's acceptable to reciprocate. *But* only less than or equal to the amount they flirt. And, at the least hint of discomfort or disinterest, you need to stop. Other people would hold the line that flirting in either direction is bad behaviour.

#### You can still be friends

Just don't leave room for confusion in your actions.

Easiest way to clear up confusion is to suggest activities in groups. Invite all the students to coffee together. Ask everyone in the lab if they want to go for pizza. Organise a day-trip with everyone together. Day to day, it's normal to get lunch with a group of colleges, and chat over lunch.

If there is only you, and one other person in you're lab, find more people. Staff who do administrative work might be pleased to join you, or perhaps another lab/work group.

When the subject is strictly work, then one to one conversations and meetings are fine. If you want to be a little more cautious, you might consider leaving the door open when it's just you and one other person in a room.

Comment: Actually I'm not so certain that the OPs preferred actions wouldn't also be considered harassment or personal misconduct even in their own country. It sounds like clear coercion.

Comment: @Buffy while I suspect you're correct, I've never worked in Latin America, so I don't know what the written rules are, let alone how things go in practice. I think it's more productive to answer under the assumption that the OP knows more about academic culture Latin America than I do. Tbh, an answer from someone who had worked in Latin America, and somewhere in Europe would be way better.

Comment: @Buffy Also, at the time I answered, OP had not yet mentioned their authorship offer... Although I'd say that the authorship misconduct is less important than not flirting with students in general; sexual harassment is worse than academic misconduct.

Comment: Even if OP does not flirt with a particular student, that student might think flirting with OP (as a power figure) is the way to go. Perhaps because the student believes that flirting with power figures generally leads to other benefits; perhaps because the student observed (or even imagined) other students gain benefits from flirting with OP and wants those benefits too. This creates the same issues as if the OP had initiated the flirting, so “flirting in either direction is bad behaviour” seems to be the correct line here. Does anyone have a good argument to the contrary?

Comment: @BrianDrake Yes, it's possible that a junior flirting with their senior is looking for unearned credit, but it's also possible they are genuinely looking for a date. Given they are junior, this advance doesn't put their senior in quite such a sticky position. Maybe it's not a great idea, but people certainly do date people they work with, even across hierarchies. A PI and a PhD student might only be 5 years apart. I've seen that happen, and I cannot judge either of them too harshly for it.

Comment: @BrianDrake Of course, this particular OP likely doesn't have the social nuance to judge that situation correctly. They missed the mark in far more blatant ones. In the end, I wish OP had accepted the "get some help" answer, but I understand why they didn't. There is only so much advice a person will accept from an internet stranger.

Comment: @Clumsycat (1/2) Of course, OP can only accept answers that exist at the time (they can change their accepted answer later, but many OP’s, like this one, seem to disappear quickly), and might be more likely to accept answers that have high scores or otherwise look better. Hovering over the green tick should indicate when this answer was accepted, which I could compare with the times of other events.

Comment: (2/2) But in this case, hovering over the green tick says: “This answer has been accepted by Community on behalf of [generic username]. The original asker’s account is deactivated.” (without giving a time) I have no idea what that means, but I do know that this  answer is pinned to the top, despite not having the highest score (or even second highest score). What is going on?

Comment: @BrianDrake Originally it was accepted by OP, then OP deleted their account. Deleted accounts cannot cast votes, or accept answers.

Comment: @BrianDrake and both answers did exist at the time. People are more likely to accept answers that appear less accusatory. Indeed, they are better at accepting advice that doesn't cause them to lose face. It's really hard to tell someone they need to get professional help with their social interactions without embarrassing them. I'd try with a close friend maybe, but with a stranger, it's kind of impossible. My intent was to answer with as much of the truth as I thought I could get OP to listen to.

Comment: I agree with @BrianDrake, "flirting back" to a student who is or may be in future "under their power" (their subordinate, or someone whom OP may/is likely to have to examine) is plain inacceptable. It would accepting the student's flirtation would also be abuse of power, and run foul of anti-corruption rules like accepting gifts from a student.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to correct your misconception here. Germans (and other Europeans) are not prude, stuck up or don't want to have fun. On the contrary. Most people here just don't perceive being on the receiving end of unwantend/inappropriate romantic or even sexual advances as "fun". They rather perceive that (rightfully so) as harrassment.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: Get professional help.

Going by your description and comments (now moved [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135084)) on the issue, you likely have a serious issue with at least one of the following (or something related):

- Judging how your communication is perceived.
- Determining the personal boundaries of others.
- Making appropriate decisions on interpersonal and ethical issues.
- Controlling your impulses.

To give just one example, [you described your own communication](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60747518#60747518) in a way that (going by your description) was sexual harassment and were not aware of this.
After many replies, you wrote that this was not intended seriously, but then neglecting this information would be a severe miscommunication on its own.
Furthermore, even jokingly saying something like this is a bad communication choice as it is not a matter to joke about and can have serious effects if the joke is not recognised as such.

Obviously, only a professional in direct conversation can judge whether the above applies and what exactly your issue is, so I will leave that to them. Cultural differences do not appear to be the root of this problem though they may exacerbate it.

Until you learn to overcome whatever the issue is with professional help, you need to keep your interactions with supervisees and co-workers on a purely professional level. Otherwise you risk to commit further errors of a similar nature, which may **severely hurt** others and further damage your career. Only after addressing these issues, you may be able to engage in non-professional and thus joyful interactions with colleagues again.

There are very likely professional services at your university that are bound by professional secrecy and can help you. Moreover, taking steps towards addressing these issues may count in your favour when the issues are investigated.

Comment: This answer could benefit from a summary of relevant comments by OP and an explanation (without relying on linked material not included in the answer) of why OP appears to have one of the issues on your list.

Comment: @BrianDrake: While I see your point to some extent, I need to balance it with not giving the impression of wanting to remote-diagnose the OP or trying to shame him. Also one of the points of the list is to emphasise that I do not know exactly *what* is going wrong here, but only *that* something is going wrong. The point of the answer is not to prove that the OP is suffering from one of these issues, neither to him nor anybody else. The point is to make the OP (and others in a similar situation) see that there is a problem on his side and he has to take steps to address it.

Answer (score 7):

#metoo exists in Latin America as well, and it has shown that male superiors "flirting" with female subordinates is not welcome there either, regardless of whether it is more common. In other words, I think you're taking the wrong approach if you're trying to figure out how you can "import" part of your notion of "having fun" from one country to another.

The suggestion I would have for you is to be quite clear in separating work and personal life. Keep your work life strictly professional. If you wouldn't say something to a male subordinate, don't say it to a female subordinate. If you wouldn't comment on male subordinates' clothes/hair/beauty products/body shape, then don't do it with your female subordinates. If you wouldn't "flirt" with your male subordinates, don't do it with the female ones.

Actually, let me revise that last paragraph: If you wouldn't say something to your mother, don't say it to a subordinate. If you wouldn't comment on your auntie's clothes/hair/beauty products/body shape, then don't do it with your subordinates. If you wouldn't "flirt" with your uncle, don't do it with your subordinates.

It may be surprising that this kind of advice would be necessary anywhere, but it is certainly appropriate advice for Germany.

Answer (score 1):

This answer mainly presents information from other answers in a different form.

> people in Europe are much more strict …

Strict about what? You only mention one example that makes sense:

> flirting with female students

Yes, Europe is more strict about this (and, according to [Wolfgang Bangerth’s answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/183658/131672), there are calls for Latin America to by more strict about this too), because it is considered an abuse of power. You have power over the students, so when you interact with them in a certain way, they may feel compelled to join in.

This is already a problem. But, even worse, the students may feel compelled to hide the fact that they do not want to participate. This may lead you to think they are willing when they are not – an even bigger problem.

These are already serious problems, even if the interaction is not sexual. If it is sexual and the student is not willing to participate, then it is sexual harassment, which is even worse, and which Europe is also strict about. If it is sexual and it is not clear whether the student is willing to participate, it may be treated the same way.

The question seems to imply that Europe is strict about romantic or sexual behaviour generally, or simply opposed to people having fun; this is all false.

> people in Europe are much more … prude.

They are not. They do not have a problem with romantic or sexual behaviour, as long as it is clear that all participants are willing.

> How can I overcome this cultural difference and enjoy my time in Germany?

Having established that the premises are false, this question takes on a new meaning, and the answer is obvious: When there is a power imbalance, keep your interactions strictly personal; when there is not, have fun as you usually would. (Of course, in all cases, you should respect people’s *personal* boundaries.)

Answer (score 0):

**Harrassment laws and polcies are strict in Europe generally.**

You may not consider what you describe as harrassment, but this would be the likely interpretation by both the student body and officialdom.

Even the appearance of misconduct can lead to serious problems, all the way up to criminal charges depending on the details.  Disciplinary problems are almost a certainty.

> It's a couple of years that I have moved to Europe and working here as a research group leader. In my home country in Latin America, we are much more relaxed in our interactions with each other and enjoy life to the fullest; that is, for example, flirting with female students and have fun is something common.

This "flirting" is almost certainly against the rules of any educational institute in Europe.

If you want fun have it with people who are *peers* in work or any non-student outside of it.  It's that simple.

The students (and those who work under you) are seen as people you can influence using your position and it's considered an abuse of authority to engage with them in that way.  You open yourself up to accusations of favoritism, abuse of power, sexual misconduct.  You don't even have to engage in any physical contact to make yourself vulnerable to these accusations.

> I have realized that people in Europe are much more strict and prude.

It's not prudishness, just an acknowledgement in law and policy that women (in particular) are very vulnerable to be influenced and misused by those with some sort of power over them or their careers.  Laws and policies now provide them with much needed protection and backup.

> How can I overcome this cultural difference and enjoy my time in Germany?

Draw a line between those you have influence over (students) and peers.  Stay on the side of the line that has no students (or people who report to you).

It's that simple.

Frankly I would not hire someone who did not understand this idea and it's importance.  Such a person would be a liability in a modern working or teaching environment.  What you said made me think "lawsuit waiting to happen".

Comment: This is the only answer that directly addresses the question as posed, and I want to upvote it for that reason. But I find the start of the answer confusing. The OP would almost certainly agree that what they are doing is not harassment, and they deserve a clear explanation of why it is. The clear implication is that flirting with a subordinate = sexual harassment, but the answer does not spell this out; in fact, it does not use the term “sexual harassment” anywhere.